# Making a tty9 on a openvz VE

Tags: tty, openvz, asterisk

I am in a virtual environment. I am installing Asterisk and freepbx. They use this script amportal and it has a requirement to check for tty9

there is alot of mention on folks running this in a VE who just modify the script to remove the tty reference i do not want to do that I want to actually add this how do I do this.

there is this  mknod  command but I really do not understand how to work it.  anyone enlighten myself and otheres on how to create a tty9!

Answer (score 2):

You not need tty for run asterisk. Just edit /usr/sbin/safe_asterisk file and find this lines:

```
TTY=9                                           # TTY (if you want    one) for Asterisk to run on  
CONSOLE=yes                                     # Whether or not you want a console
```

change to

```
TTY=
CONSOLE=no
```

That will allow start asterisk on openvz.

You still will have output of verbose log in logfiles(by default /var/log/asterisk/full)

Note: for conference you also need add to openvz container properties (on host node)

```
DEVNODES="dahdi/ctl:rw dahdi/pseudo:rw "
```

+ need compile dahdi on hardware node.

PS Asterisk can give sound  issues on some vps, that is not fixable if you not control hardware node. Solution: got vps with more power or vps for asterisk(marked as "asterisk compatible").